# Unclear precedence of bitshift operation

Tags: php, bit, bit-shift, operator-precedence

I've been struggling with the shift operator in PHP, assuming that it precedes arithmetic operations like +, 1 etc. I've been unable to find any definition of this in the php manual.

Let's say that I have the value 1, which I want to 3, then to 7 etc., filling bits from the right (LSB).

I tried:

```
$X = 1;
```

Then, in a loop:

```
$X <<= 1 + 1; // returns 4 instead of 3.
$X <<= 1 + 1; // returns 16 instead of 7.
```

So evidently 1+1 is calculated BEFORE the shift.
My solution:

```
$X = 1;
$X <<= 1; // $X=2
$X += 1;  // $X=3 as expected
$X <<= 1; // $X=6
$X += 1;  // $X=7 as expected
```

Which is a bit more clumsy, but this returns the right numbers. Shouldn't the first method produce the correct result, shifting first and THEN do the arithmetic?

Comment: `+` is higher precedence https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php Use `($X <<= 1) + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

`$X <<= 1 + 1`

is converted into:

`$X = $X << (1 + 1)`

if you want to do it differently, then you can use:

`$X = ($X << 1) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

See the [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) table and explanations.  The `+` operator is higher precedence than `<<=`. You can force precedence by grouping with parentheses `()`:

```
$X = ($X <<= 1) + 1;
```

Also note:

> Use of parentheses, even when not strictly necessary, can often increase readability of the code by making grouping explicit rather than relying on the implicit operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: for short assignment forms, higher precedence of `+` does not matter (what `$x = 2;$x *= 2+3;` will return?, also - there is no sense in double assignment

Comment: WTF are you talking about? That returns 10 obviously because `+` higher precedence than `*=`.

Comment: I'm talking about associativity, operators like `a op= b` are executed with right associativity, which basically means that they are treated like `a = a op (b)` and this is why precedence does not matter here, also `($X <<= 1) + 1;` will not work for op

Comment: Associativity only applies when precedence is the same, so yes, precedence does matter here as the precedence is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments!
Actually, '<<=' is not only an operator, but also an assignment, so

```
$X <<= 1 + 1 will be interpreted as $X <<= 2.
$X = $X << 1 + 1 might possibly work (I haven't checked), but
$X = ($X << 1) + 1 as suggested by Ilya would be the right way.
```